# Is there a way to have the labels of data auto-populated to my barplot?

Tags: r

Am working on plotting a barplot of the no.of matches won by teams in IPL. How do I add names of the teams in the plot?

''' barplot(pointstable$Won, main= "Winning Distribution",xlab="Name of the team", ylab="No. of matches won")'''

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uG6HN.png)

Comment: Use the argument `names.arg`

Comment: Welcome to SO and R. To help us help you please put your code and data in the question. You may find it helpful to write an excellent question by following the guidance in this link [MRE]. Please, please add some data in a dataframe format e.g. df <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3), b = c("a", "b", "c")) obviously with your own data! And either explain what your have tried out prior to asking your question, ideally with the code you have tried. Thank you.